# Change $form_state in AJAX callback

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am creating a form which uses the form API `'#ajax'` attribute, and I need to make changes to `$form_state` when the AJAX-enabled button is pressed. Here's what I've got:

Inside my form builder function:

```
...
$form['some_fieldset']['add_more'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Add more rows'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'wrapper' => 'some-fieldset',
        'callback' => 'my_module_settings_ajax',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
    );

...
```

And here's the callback function:

```
function my_module_settings_ajax($form, $form_state) { 
  // Make a change to $form_state
  if ($form_state['some_fieldset']['add_more']) {
    $form_state['values']['some_fieldset']['table'][] = array('first_field' => '',
                                                                'second_field' => '');
  }

  return $form['some_fieldset'];
}
```

The change I've made to `$form_state` seem to be lost once the callback has finished. Is there any way to make a change to `$form_state` in this function, or there any other function I should use for this instead?

**EDIT**

As it turns out, the callback is the wrong place to do this logic. Instead, at the top of the form builder function, I added this:

```
// Respond to AJAX-triggger:
// Add new row
if ($form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] == 'add_more') {
  $form_state['values']['some_fieldset']['table'][] = array('first_field' => '',
                                                                'second_field' => '');
}
```

Of course, I had to give the button the name:

```
$form['some_fieldset']['add_more'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#name' => 'add_more', // <-- Right here
  '#value' => t('Add more rows'),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'wrapper' => 'some-fieldset',
    'callback' => 'my_module_settings_ajax',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
  ),
);
```

And now it works!

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `$form_state` as reference; the AJAX function needs to be defined as in the following example:

```
function mymodule_settings_ajax($form, &$form_state) { /* … */ }
```

Comment: To clarify, you need the & to pass by reference rather than by value. Without it you are only modifying a copy of $form_state.

Comment: Yes, if you don't do this, you only modify a local variable.

Comment: Of course, didn't think of that. Unfortunately, it didn't have any effect - any change made to $form_state is ignored in the form builder, and the next time the AJAX call is made, $form_state is reverted. Could it be that the form has already been generated by the time the callback executes? Is there a way to run a custom submit-handler for this button instead?

Comment: Try to change the type from button to submit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's a direct answer to your question, but it may work for you use case: Instead of changing the $form_state add values to your $form. If you don't want them to show just use `#hidden`.